# curl/curl.h: No such file or directory even tho vcpkg created directory vcpg_installed in build and there is curl/curl.h there

Tags: c++, linux, cmake, libcurl, vcpkg

So I'm trying to use curl.h in c++ my main.cpp is just hello world but with include curl/curl.h:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(){
    std::cout<<"hello world!";

    return 0;
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
add_executable(main)
target_sources(main PRIVATE main.cpp)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake CACHE STRING "Vcpkg toolchain file")
project(web_crawler)
find_package(libcurl-simple-https CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

I am new to both vcpkg and CMake and I am trying to learn it thats why it looks like this.

and my vcpkg.json is:

```
{
  "name": "webcrawler",
  "version-string": "latest",
  "dependencies": [
    "libcurl-simple-https"
  ]
}
```

cmake build seems to work fine and when i use make I'm getting this:

```
fatal error: curl/curl.h: No such file or directory
    2 | #include <curl/curl.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/main.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/main.dir/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/main.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

As I already told I am new to both cmake and vcpkg so I have no idea what to do and couldn't find any similar post as most of them are about installing curl.

Comment: sounds like you need libcurl-dev or the equivalent package nowadays for your linux distro

Comment: `find_package(libcurl-simple-https CONFIG REQUIRED)` sets some CMake variables and properties but does not add an include directory or link or anything like that. You need to do these yourself with additional CMake commands.

Comment: the point of package managers like `vcpkg` is that you don't have to install the library with the system specific mechanisms. It's not clear if `curl` is installed in `vcpkg`: what's the output of `./vcpkg install curl`

Comment: yes curl was indeed installed but when I ran ./vcpkg install curl, I got this: 
curl is compatible with built-in CMake targets:

    find_package(CURL REQUIRED)
    target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE CURL::libcurl) 
so I used it in CMakeLists.txt and it finally worked but during installation two days ago I got different commands:  find_package(libcurl-simple-https CONFIG REQUIRED) target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libcurl-simple-https) so I was using those and that's what caused errors thank you guys for help

Answer (score -1):

Wild guess here, but after this line:

```
find_package(libcurl-simple-https CONFIG REQUIRED)
```

Did you not forget to add the include directory for it?  So the next line should be something like:

```
include_directories(${libcurl-simple-https_dirs})
```

What I've done in other projects is:

```
FIND_PACKAGE(CURL)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CURL_INCLUDE_DIR})
```

You'll have to check the spelling and possibly the case since I'm not familiar with the name you used, "libcurl-simple-https".

Comment: adding include_directories(${libcurl-simple-https_dirs}) doesn't help and vcpkg gave me this: # this is heuristically generated, and may not be correct
  find_package(libcurl-simple-https CONFIG REQUIRED)
  target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libcurl-simple-https)
but when I add this: target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE libcurl-simple-https) CMake is throwing that:
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:9 (add_executable):
  Target "main" links to target "CURL::libcurl" but the target was not found.
  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or an
  ALIAS target is missing?

Comment: You need to install libcurl-dev on your Linux